# Why does my cat scratch wall around litter box?

Tags: cats, scratching, cat-litter

We have a single cat in my apartment around 10 months old. We notice that after he is done peeing/pooping he covers his waste in the litter box but starts scratching the wall around the litter box. It seems like he thinks the wall is an extension of his litter box. At times he will cover his waste, scratch the wall and come back after sometime to repeat scratching. We have recorded a 30s video which can be found here: https://youtu.be/NkgZUr-NN34

This is not really an issue but it is an annoyance, because he wakes us up in the middle of the night with his scratching. Can we do anything to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Letting your cat go to the toilet in the right place takes some time to train him

Comment: in addition to the linked question... try a white noise generator. White noise/rain sounds/etc will blend with the noise and help keep it from waking you. I had a cat do this for his entire 14 years, and now have another who's been doing it for two. You get used to it.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks for the feedback and the linked question.